# Scheduling in Laravel 5.5 is not properly working

Tags: laravel, cron, laravel-5.5

I have created a command file in commands folder with name "Tournaments" and $signature = 'tournament:start', then updated in Kernal.php file with this command :

```
$schedule->command('tournament:start')->everyFiveMinutes()->appendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/examplecommand.log'));
```

Then set the cron job in server like this:

```
*/5 **** php /directory path/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

But the query is not executed. What could be the problem ? did i miss anything in the scheduling process ?

Comment: can you add  `$schedule->call(function () { logger()->info(now()); })->cron('* * * * *');` into you schedule and check your log

Answer (score 0):

The proper line to insert in the cronfile is:

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Also, be sure that your command is properly registered: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan#registering-commands

Comment: I have updated the cronjob command like your one : 
`php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: Still its not executing..but when i try in localhost with cmd prompt its executing properly php artisan tournament:start

Answer (score 0):

Since Your Code is Looking Good

So this Must be in `App\Console\Kernel.php` under `schedule` function

```
/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
     $schedule->command('tournament:start')
    ->everyFiveMinutes()
    ->appendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/examplecommand.log'));

     $schedule->call(function () {
        logger()->info(now());
    })->cron('* * * * *');

}
```

So the `tournament:start` Will run Every Fiveminutes

But as You need to  change the cron entry in the server to check for every minutes

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Here is the cron Entry in my server

[image]

and here is my schedule function

```
/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
     $schedule->command('generate:report')
             ->hourly()
             ->between('5:00', '23:00');

    $schedule->command('sendEmail:deviceOffline')
             ->everyThirtyMinutes()
             ->between('5:00', '23:00');

}
```

so `generate:report` will run hourly between 5:00 AM and 11::00 PM

And `sendEmail:deviceOffline` will run run every thiry minutes between 5:00 AM and 11::00 PM

Comment: When i try with cmd php artisan tournament:start , the query is executed. Its not working via cron job,there is no logs also created. No errors...what will be the issue ?